# Page Resizing Through JQuery .fadeIn, .fadeOut looks bad

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to have different `div` elements fade in and out based on links that are clicked on the page.  It works fine, but whenever 1 element is fading out and another is fading in at the same time, the page size gets altered pretty drastically and it looks "glitchy."  Putting a delay basically has the same effect because the page will decrease in size once one fades out and then increase ones the other fades in.

I would like to try `position:absolute` with a set height but I'd also like to have it so the user has an option to load ALL divs at once, and they would overlap.

I could try other animations that look smoother, but I like the fade.

Has anyone else had experience working around this?  Is there a way to delay the page from resizing, lol?

Comment: Why not simply make a container div with a specified height and then put your fade content inside that? Then, you could fade out one element (and the parent div prevents the page from resizing), and then fade in your new element.

Comment: hey Tejs.  I wanted to avoid doing this because some content is several paragraphs, so making a container div would require a huge blank spot on the page, and I'd don't think it would look good.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same problem. The way I got around it was by getting the current height of the parent div using the outerHeight() JQuery function and then setting the min-height of the div to the current height before calling the fadeOut function on the child div.

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv1">
    <div id="mydiv2">
        <!-- Elements to faded in and out -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var current_height = $('#mydiv1').outerHeight();
$("#mydiv1").css("min-height", current_height);

$('#mydiv2').fadeOut('slow', function()
{
    // Animation complete.
});
```

This is an old question I know, but I hope that helps anybody who has found there way here.